# Watermark Bug in Magento

Tags: watermark

When will the watermark bug be fixed in Magento 2.2.2 -- will this be an issue in Magento 2.2.4?

I have tried to add a watermark and I get this error:
Backend model is not specified for watermark_image_image

I have been told that it is a known bug.