# 2.3.0 Watermarks not showing on product images

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, watermark

Watermarks are not showing up on product images in v2.3.0.

**Steps to reproduce**

1. Create categories
2. Create products
3. Modify [buggy image uploader](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/252256/magento-2-3-favicon-and-logo-upload-does-not-take-hold) to work around bug so you actually can upload an image.
4. Upload a watermark (use [watermark in this issue](https://github.com/magento/magento2/pull/17623)  as a watermark example)
5. set image opacity to 10, image size to 40x50, image position to tile, and saved configuration.
6. tap the Cache Management link in the system message. Then, refresh the invalid cache.

2.3.0 [Docs](https://docs.magento.com/m2/ce/user_guide/catalog/product-image-watermarks.html) state:

Complete the Base, Thumbnail, Small, and Swatch Image image settings as follows. The fields in each section are the same.

1. Enter the Image Opacity as a percentage. For example: 40
2. Enter the Image Size, in pixels. For example: 200 x 200
3. Tap Upload, and choose the image file that you want to use.
4. Set Image Position to determine where the watermark appears.
5. When complete, tap Save Config .
6. When prompted to refresh the cache, tap the Cache Management link in the system message. Then, refresh the invalid cache. Even tried to clear all available clear catch options inside cache management.

....still no watermark on product images.

2.3.0 Installation
No third party modules
No errors in browser console, or magento logs.

Opened [ticket](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/21154)
And posted in [forum](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Watermark-not-showing-on-images/m-p/121505#M8170)

Other users with similar problem but some on older than 2.3:
[here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Magento-2-2-5-Watermark/m-p/108876), [here](https://community.magento.com/t5/Magento-2-x-Technical-Issues/Watermark-not-showing/m-p/99395), [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/238398/watermark-bug-in-magento), [here](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/261460/can-t-set-watermark-in-magento-2-3-0)

How do you resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try with a gif? I think that worked for us before.